# Go inside of settings on button press

Tags: android-activity, android-widget, android

I'm new to android application development. My question is how to show **directly** inside of android settings on press of a button of an application.

example on button press show directly VPN settings or Tethering & portable hotspot settings.

Comment: check [Setting intent on android developer blogs]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Answer (score 2):

try this way working in `4.0.4` not tested in another version

```
Intent tetherSettings = new Intent();
tetherSettings.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings");
startActivity(tetherSettings);
```

Comment: thanx @Simple Plan, I'll try this one.